# Why do I get a string encoding issue "\xE2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, utf-8, ascii

I'm trying to download a PDF from an email and write the contents to a file. For some reason, I'm getting this error:

```
An Encoding::UndefinedConversionError occurred in attachments#inbound: "\xE2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 app/controllers/api/attachments_controller.rb:70:in `write'
```

Here's my code:

```
def inbound
    if Rails.env.production? or Rails.env.staging?
      email = Postmark::Mitt.new(request.body.read)
    else
      email = Postmark::Mitt.new(File.binread "#{Rails.root}/app/temp_pdfs/email.json")
    end

    if email.attachments.count == 0
      # notify aidin that we got an inbound email with no attachments
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
      return
    end
    attachment = email.attachments.first
    filename = "attachment" + (Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")+(rand * 1000000).round.to_s) + ".pdf"
    base_path = "#{Rails.root}/temp_attachments/"
    unless File.directory?(base_path)
      Dir::mkdir(base_path)
    end
    file = File.new base_path + filename, 'w+'
    file.write Base64.decode64(attachment.source['Content'].encode("UTF-16BE", :invalid=>:replace, :replace=>"?").encode("UTF-8"))
    file.close
    write_options = write_options()
    write_options[:metadata] = {:filename => attachment.file_name, :content_type => attachment.content_type, :size => attachment.size }

    obj = s3_object()
    file = File.open file.path
    obj.write(file.read, write_options)
    file.close

    FaxAttach.trigger obj.key.split('/').last

    render :nothing => true, :status => 202 and return
  end
```

I read around and it looked like the way to solve this was:

```
file.write Base64.decode64(attachment.source['Content'].encode("UTF-16BE", :invalid=>:replace, :replace=>"?").encode("UTF-8"))
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Could you add the data excerpt that is failing to convert, with the problem `\xE2` (the error message is technically correct, there is no character associated with `\xE2` in ASCII-8BIT)? My best guess is that you will need to force encoding of the data you have read  - possibly something like `.force_encoding("ISO-8859-1")` - before Ruby will know what to do with that character. Of course, if you force the encoding, you may choose wrong, so it might be worth finding out what the character is in the PDF.

Comment: @NeilSlater Sure, give me two seconds. It's all base 64 encoded, so I'll decode it and post the output

Comment: @NeilSlater Actually, when I base 64 decode, it gives me a bunch of gibberish. https://gist.github.com/chintanparikh/5859337

Comment: I've not read your whole question properly, just focussing on the error message. Am I right in thinking you are wanting to save a binary file sent as an email attachment? If so, there should be no need to manage character encodings, you will almost definitely corrupt the file if you change the encoding.

Comment: Which email handling gem are you using?

Comment: @NeilSlater Postmark-Mitt

Comment: And yeah, It'd be a binary file I think. Any idea how else I should do it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The error message is actually being thrown on the file write, not by your encode/decode inside the params, because Ruby is trying to apply default character encoding on `file.write`. To prevent this, the quickest fix is to add the `b` flag when you open the file

```
file = File.new base_path + filename, 'wb+'
file.write Base64.decode64( attachment.source['Content'] )
```

That's assuming the incoming attachment is encoded in Base64, as your code implies (I have no way to verify this). The Base64 encoding stored inside `attachment.source['Content']` should be the same bytes in ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8, so there is no point converting it inside the call to `decode64`.

Comment: Doesn't error out anymore, but also doesn't work. It might be another step in the process though, so I'll mark this as solved. Cheers!